# How to calculate positions of XML elements using XSL?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a list of items in XML (mind the duplicates):

```
<root>
  <a>hello</a>
  <a>bye</a>
  <a>5</a>
  <a>hello</a>
  <a>8</a>
</root>
```

I want to translate it to this:

```
<root>
  <a>4</a>
  <a>3</a>
  <a>1</a>
  <a>4</a>
  <a>2</a>
</root>
```

Essentially, I'm replacing values with their positions in a sorted list of all values (comparing text to text). I'm trying to do this using `<xsl:key>`, but can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: Are you really limited to XSLT 2 or can't you just use XSLT 3? Given that most people use some version of Saxon for XSLT 2 but Saxon since version 9.8 supports XSLT 3 I wonder where the focus on XSLT 2 comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try perhaps:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="sorted">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="a">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:perform-sort> 
    </xsl:variable> 
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <a>
                <xsl:value-of select="index-of(distinct-values($sorted/a), .)"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or maybe a bit more elegantly:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="sorted" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="distinct-values(a)">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:perform-sort> 
    </xsl:variable> 
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <a>
                <xsl:value-of select="index-of($sorted, .)"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or even just simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="sorted">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="a">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:perform-sort> 
    </xsl:variable> 
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <a>
                <xsl:value-of select="index-of($sorted/a, .)[1]"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```